# how to change 123456.654321 to 12:34:56:654321 in Pandas Dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm having a pandas dataframe with column 'tim' as a string of data like:

```
103808.827565
103808.827583
103808.827568
103808.827665
```

e.g. 103808.82

Answer (score 2):

Parse non-standard time formats with `pd.to_datetime` and then subtract the origin '1900-01-01', leaving you with a `timedelta64[ns]`.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime(df['tim'], format='%H%M%S.%f') - pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01')
0   10:38:08.827565
1   10:38:08.827583
2   10:38:08.827568
3   10:38:08.827665
Name: tim, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much ALollz! You really saved my day!